# PDO SQL error (While inserting)

Tags: php, pdo

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php:47 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php(47): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php on line 47
```

This is my code:

```
// This checks if variabes are not empty, and if username is less than 11 characters long.
if (!empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($message) && strlen($username) < 11) {

    // Shortcut for our ID generator function.
    $ID = generateID();

    // Now lets insert (register the account) these datas to our database.
    $insert = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, message, date, time, id) VALUES (:username, :password, :message, CURDATE(), CURTIME(), :id");

    // Executing in array, because if we binded all these variables, it would look very bad.
    $insert->execute(array(
        ':username' => $username,       
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':message' => $message, 
        ':id' => $ID
    ));

    if (!$insert->execute()) {
        print_r($insert->errorInfo());
    }       
}
```

I am new to PHP, pretty much, and many people telling me to start using PDO, before mysql_ will be out dated.

So I started, and it seems really hard.
Trying to get used to it.

What did I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: (:username, :password, :message, CURDATE(), CURTIME(), :id)"  you forgot the ending parentheses for the VALUES( ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` and `time` are keywords. Please escape them using backticks.

---

You are missing the parentheses for your `VALUES` clause.

---

The `prepare` statement should be:

```
$insert = $connect->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, message, `date`, `time`, id )
        VALUES( :username, :password, :message, CURDATE(), CURTIME(), :id )"
);
```

Comment: Keywords, yes. Reserved, no. Those don't require quoting. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function CURDATE()
Any idea what is that error?

Comment: @purepksorpurepk CURDATE = current Date; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate  view the manual of usages

Comment: @purepksorpurepk If you are getting `call to undefined function CURDATE(), that would imply that you are calling MysQL's function CURDATE() in PHP context. Did you close and reopen quotes around it?

Comment: I don't think so, atleast not that I know of.
http://pastebin.com/juCKuJkC <- This is my code.

Comment: You don't need to break the query string.

Comment: @Dream Eater

What was the problem? Thanks a lot mate!.

Comment: The error was because you were breaking your query string. PHP tried to execute `CURDATE()` on its own, instead of passing it as a function for MySQL to operate on. @purepksorpurepk

Comment: Oh, I see now, thanks.
I know this error is a bit off topic but (sorry about that)

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php:62 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php(62): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\recover\recover.php on line 62

line 62 is the excute array

Answer (score 3):

VALUES doesn't have a closing bracket.